# My flex application breaks when I declare an AnalyticsTracker from com.google.analylitics / GAForflash

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, google-analytics, flex4

I have a running flex application. It is a video player with a playlist. I'm following the instructions here to add google analytics tracking:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingSetupFlex

And I have tried both the flex example and the actionscript 3 example, which is also really a flex application, but the instantiation is done inside the  tags. I am currently leaning toward the latter, but as the code snippet below shows, I have tried both.

I am doing a command line compilation with a shell script wrapper with this command:

```
${FLEX_SDK_PATH}/bin/mxmlc -load-config+=./compile.xml -debug=${d} -output=${OUT}${mid}.swf ${SRC}.mxml
```

my included compile.xml looks like this:

```
<flex-config>
    <swf-version>13</swf-version>
    <compiler>
        <external-library-path append="true">
            <path-element>libs/analytics.swc</path-element>
        </external-library-path>
        <external-library-path append="true">
            <path-element>libs/fiber-4.5.0.307554.swc</path-element>
        </external-library-path>
    </compiler>
</flex-config>
```

When I create a variable or declaration to hold the AnalyticsTracker the player compiles, but it fails to run. Instead of my video player I just get a blank white screen. I comment out that variable declaration, recompile, and it runs as is should. I am sure that I'm pulling the analytics.swc in because if I wasn't I'd get a compilation error.  This is a fairly large application (1987 lines) so this is just a snippet:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
              applicationComplete="applicationCompleteHandler(event)" 
              creationComplete="init(event)"           
    ...
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
    ...
        import com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker;
        import com.google.analytics.GATracker
    ...  
        // If I uncomment this the application still compiles,
        // but it will not run
        // public var gAnalytic:AnalyticsTracker;

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            Security.allowDomain("*");
            Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
            // this.gAnalytic = new GATracker(this,"UA-xxxxxx-10","AS3",true);
        }
     ...
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
     ...
    </s:states>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- If I uncomment this declaration, the application will compile but not run -->
        <!-- 
        <analytics:FlexTracker
            xmlns:analytics="com.google.analytics.components.*"
            id="gAnalytic"
            account="UA-xxxxxx-10"
            mode="AS3"
            visualDebug="true"
            />
        -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    ...
    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

I am watching a tail of the trace output and I have lots of debugging coming out related the rest of the application. If I give it a run with the comment above removed, I get nothing. None of my traces, no unCaught exception, nothing...

Any ideas? Just where to look for an error message would help as I'm not seeing anything in flashlog. I'm pretty new to flash/flex and inherited this project.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your post, your SWF version 13, which means your are using old version of flex. GA compiled for later versions of flash/flex. You should use Apache Flex, at least it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I went from 4.6 to 4.13, which seems to be the latest stable release. I'm sure that was a good move in general, but I'm still having this problem.

Comment: Did you checked checkbox Package (in a list of ANEs attached to project)? Sometimes it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember the details now, but I had a few problems using GATracker as well. It may not be of much help, but I think the time of instantiation was important. Anyway, I ended up wrapping it in my own class like below, and delayed calling init() until all the app was set up.

```
    public function GoogleAnalyticsTracker(
        account:String,
        mode:String = 'AS3',
        visualDebug:Boolean = false
    ){
        this.account        = account;
        this.mode           = mode;
        this.visualDebug    = visualDebug;
    }

    public function init(do:DisplayObject):void
    {
        ga = new GATracker(do, account, mode, visualDebug);
    }
```

Make sure you pass it a DisplayObject, too:

```
this.gAnalytic = new GATracker(DisplayObject(this), "UA-xxxxxx-10", "AS3", true);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that once I do get to the point where I can declare an AnalyticsTracker, I need to make sure I am actually passing it a DisplayObject. As it is now, just declaring a variable of type AnalyticsTracker breaks it. I tried declaring it and setting it to null with no change in behavior, i.e., it don't work.

Comment: Try to declare it in a class that is not called until Stage/App is ready. This way you (probably) avoid initiating some GA code prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

gaforflash is obsolete and legacy now

check out as3-universal-analytics
https://github.com/zwetan/as3-universal-analytics/releases/tag/0.8

the setup is easier and more modular so it should solve your problems